# valgrind cachegrind - what is good result

Tags: c++, caching, valgrind

I tried to run the cachegrind tool from valgrind and got the following output.

Background:

Usually we develop scientific programs, where it does not really matter if your program runs for 1 second or 3 seconds. But in my current project the run time is much longer and I thought it might be a good idea to look into this tools. Usually I only use callgrind to profile my result.

```
--14387-- warning: L3 cache found, using its data for the LL simulation.
==14387== brk segment overflow in thread #1: can't grow to 0x4a44000
==14387== (see section Limitations in user manual)
==14387== NOTE: further instances of this message will not be shown
==14387== 
==14387== I   refs:      3,642,827,372
==14387== I1  misses:        8,022,355
==14387== LLi misses:           13,650
==14387== I1  miss rate:          0.22%
==14387== LLi miss rate:          0.00%
==14387== 
==14387== D   refs:      1,343,730,074  (903,280,204 rd   + 440,449,870 wr)
==14387== D1  misses:       37,368,579  ( 34,410,595 rd   +   2,957,984 wr)
==14387== LLd misses:          361,568  (    187,256 rd   +     174,312 wr)
==14387== D1  miss rate:           2.8% (        3.8%     +         0.7%  )
==14387== LLd miss rate:           0.0% (        0.0%     +         0.0%  )
==14387== 
==14387== LL refs:          45,390,934  ( 42,432,950 rd   +   2,957,984 wr)
==14387== LL misses:           375,218  (    200,906 rd   +     174,312 wr)
==14387== LL miss rate:            0.0% (        0.0%     +         0.0%  )
```

I understand the basic theory behind cache hierarchy, cache lines and why it is bad if you miss. 
My problem is, that I have no real world experience in this topic. This mean I simply do not know how common it is to miss a L3 cache, or L1 cache.

Is there some sort of "rule of thumb" that describes when I have to worry about this topics and focus more on memory alignment and stuff like this?

Comment: Does callgrind show any hotspots? What makes you think that there is a cache issue? The valgrind manual describes the format here http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cg-manual.html. I wrote an article on this about 5 years ago, here https://accu.org/index.php/journals/1886.

Comment: Thank you for your help and you links. I will read your article. My main question was not how to read the result, I have read the manual.
I was more interesting in what one would expect in a real world example... is it for example good that the D1 miss rate is 2.8%? Is 2.8 considered very high, or is it very low? I beliefe this is depends highly on your application, I was just interested in some rule of thumb. Maybe someone would say: Hey look, you have that many cache misses, you are doing something incredible wrong... or quite the opposite.
I hope it gets clearer when I read your articles.

Comment: I've never seen much in the way of concrete guidance for what is a good hit rate for the caches, particularly as this is very dependant on the architecture and cache sizes. Intal has some VTune oriented docs here https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/processor-specific-performance-analysis-papers which say that you should investigate cache miss rates over 5%.